# Is it possible to implement dynamic batching with Kafka Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, batch-processing

Now I'm doing some tests with Apache Kafka. In the configuration of Kafka Producer the parameters **batch.size** and **linger.ms** controls the batching strategy. Is it possible to make these parameters dynamically while producing? e.g. If the data ingestion rate rises fast, we may want to increase **batch.size** to accumulate more messages per batch. I failed to find any example of dynamic batching with Kafka Producer. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but you would have to close and re-open a new Producer instance yourself with the updated configurations during runtime, while making sure that you aren't dropping events between that action.